# Jenkins: Build when a branch is tagged

Tags: git, jenkins

(Git newcomer here) I'm trying to implement a system whereby a Jenkins build is triggered when a tag is pushed to a specific branch. Currently, my supervisor has installed a simple PoC where, on our API servers (which run node.js), a cron job is ran every 5 minutes that runs:

```
git checkout production
git pull
git checkout `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`
```

So when a developer wants to push a change to production, they simply run `npm version patch` which tags the latest commit with a new version number, then pushes the change using `git push origin --tags`. Then, they run a script via Jenkins that restarts all API services on API boxes.

So, to emulate this and fully automate it, I want to have a Jenkins job that does all of this (plus some extras) when it detects our `production` branch has been tagged with a new version.

Is this possible? Most documentation I've found involves triggering a build on ANY tag pushed to a repo. I want to trigger on a tag pointing to a commit to a specific repo.

I'm fairly certain this is an advanced case, and I could write some script to do it instead, but I'm attempting to learn best practices for Jenkins and git, and I don't want to end up adhering to some anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I have *no clue* how Jenkins actually gets used, so this answer may be quite useless.

In Git, however, if you plan to use a detached HEAD like this, all you need is to run `git describe` twice, once before fetching, and once after:

```
otag=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 origin/production) ||
    die "help, no initial tag"
git fetch origin
ntag=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 origin/production) ||
    die "help, no new tag"
if [ "$otag" = "$ntag" ]; then
    echo the tag we would check out now is the same as the one
    echo we checked out last time, so we do nothing
else
    echo moving from tag: $otag to tag: $ntag
    git checkout $ntag
    ... build ...
fi
```

`git describe` allows you to specify the commit you want described, so there is no need to check out a branch, fetch, and merge-and-hope-it's-a-fast-forward.

Note that this allows the local branch `production` to get progressively more and more out of date, or even simply to not exist at all, because the local branch is *never really used*.  The only thing it is giving you in your example code is its upstream setting.